# Map local drive to another letter

Tags: windows-server-2003

Application that is developed age ago contains fixed locations in it self like

f:\inetpub\wwwroot...\some_pdf.pdf, so no on new server there is no f disk no chance to get it in short time, now what I need is map C: disk to be also as F:, I need them both.

Windows Server 2003 Service pack 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The presence of 'wwwroot' strongly suggests that this drive-letter needs to be visible to the IIS service process. Is this with IIS?

Comment: yes it is, now I have resolved this problem with location, but how to make it visible to iis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this from the command prompt:

```
subst f: c:\

C:\>dir f:
 Volume in drive F is System
 Volume Serial Number is 1234-5678

 Directory of F:\

06/10/2009  10:42 PM                24 autoexec.bat
12/05/2009  02:07 AM    <DIR>          Boot
06/10/2009  10:42 PM                10 config.sys
02/16/2011  10:04 AM    <DIR>          Program Files
02/18/2011  04:31 PM    <DIR>          Users
01/03/2011  09:57 AM    <DIR>          Windows
               2 File(s)          2,093 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  104,560,091,136 bytes free

C:\>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add it to the computer's startup script, otherwise you need to do it again after every reboot.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution to this would be to share the folder containing the application, then map a drive to the that folder and use the drive letter F.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subst` command

`subst f: c:\`

This isn't persistent across reboots so you'll need to put it in a startup batch file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the system drive, you can add another drive letter in Disk Management.  Incidentally you can also map the drive as a folder on another NTFS drive.